# how does ZGC do concurrent mark without using write barrier?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

recently I read some articles about ZGC.
eg. https://dinfuehr.github.io/blog/a-first-look-into-zgc/
And it said there is no write-barrier in ZGC.

> Both reading and writing in the heap is extremely common, so both GC-barriers need to be super efficient. That means just a few assembly instructions in the common case. Read barriers are an order of magnitude more likely than write-barriers (although this can certainly vary depending on the application), so read-barriers are even more performance-sensitive. Generational GC’s for example usually get by with just a write barrier, no read barrier needed. ZGC needs a read barrier but no write barrier. For concurrent compaction I haven’t seen a solution without read barriers.

Write-barrier has no need for concurrent compact, but how does it do concurrent mark without write-barrier? some collectors, like G1, using tri-color marking and SATB+write barrier to do concurrent mark.

And I read from OJ there is another way :

> An alternative approach would be to keep a queue of all changes that could potentially violate the invariant, and then have a secondary “fixup” phase that runs after the main phase has finished. Different collectors can resolve this problem with tri-color marking in different ways, based on criteria such as performance or the amount of locking required.

I wonder how it works... There is little information about it after searching a while...(maybe I should read some source code....

Comment: I might be missing the point, but where exactly did you concluded about this part: _but how does it do concurrent mark without write-barrier_? It seems to me that the article mentions that ZGC needs a read barrier for the _compactation phase_, not `marking`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood there is no need in a write barrier because root references from relocation set are handled on the STW phase before concurrent relocation. Therefore you will never have a reference to old object from stack, from local variable and etc.

Comment: what you are talking about is the _compactation_ phase, what the OP is asking is about _marking_ phase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's strongly related to ZGC, you should know about the tri-color mark

The following is my personal understanding I can't guarantee correct as I am new to GC.

Conditions for missing conditions:

- Grey object disconnects from white object
- The black object creates a new connection to the white object
  (There are GIFs of this on the web, but I don't know how to upload pictures)

The above conditions can be abstracted into

```
var whiteObj = getWhiteObj() // read operate ①
grayObj.whiteObj = null // write opt ②
blackObJ.XX = whiteObj // write opt ③
```

For the above code, there are three ways to achieve the problem of missing targets in concurrent marking

①: Read barrier (that is, what you need, currently used by ZGC)

When ① occurs, whiteObj is recorded, and in the next stage (final mark), these recorded objects are traversed once

② and ③ are both write barriers, which are implemented by incremental update and STAB respectively. This is not what you need. If you are interested, I believe there will be a better explanation than me in the tri-color mark blog.